# Digi Xbee XCTU Software - rebuild Network Discovery Tool

Tags: xbee, zigbee, mesh-network, device-discovery

For evaluation, I would like to rebuild the network discovery tool from the XCTU Software provides by Digi.

This tool is somehow possible to request all nodes and their connections including information about link quality within the network. I´ve not found so far, which commands are used to collect this information.

Does someone know how to obtain this information?

Answer (score 2):

To start with, `ATND` will give you a list of nodes on the network.  Sending a remote `ATMP` to end devices will give you the 16-bit network address of their parent.  On a mesh network, coordinators and routers won't have a parent.

I'm not sure how it's compiling link quality information, you could monitor the serial communications between X-CTU and the XBee radio module to determine how.  I know that for some modules (DigiMesh, 868) they support an `ATNO` setting of 2, which adds the RSSI value as a field to the Node Discovery responses.

Comment: Thanks, i will evaluate your hints.

Comment: Just read through the AT Commands of the Telegesis ZigBee Chips, which are quite different to the once of digi. Am i right that the only way to communicate interoperably though ZigBee devices from several vendors are the api frame usage?

Comment: For interoperability, you need to have the ZigBee Device Profile (ZDP) running on endpoint 0, and use ZigBee Cluster Library (ZCL) standard on your other endpoints.  Many of the XBee features are proprietary (remote AT commands, I/O sampling, transparent serial, AT mode) and won't work with other products.  I have written an Open Source C library (https://github.com/tomlogic/xbee_ansic_library) that implements ZDP and ZCL with XBee modules if you want to go that route.

Comment: Hi Tomlogic, thanks your lib looks great. But my target is a little bit different. I want to build a tool which can read configuration and network details from a ZigBee Network build on different ZigBee Chips (Xbee, Telegesis, ...). Do you know if this tool already exists? I´ve not found anything during my search so far so i decided to try building this tool on my one.

Comment: Different chips will use different APIs to access their configuration and network settings.  Write your program to interface to a specific type of ZigBee node in order to gain access to a network, and then use standard ZigBee protocols for network discovery.  That library includes another sample demonstrating the use of ZDP and ZCL discovery to dump a list of endpoints, clusters and attributes for a device on the network.